# Cosmos db - FeedResponse properties values missing

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, cosmos

While executing below cosmos document db sdk code against **non partitioned collection** I am getting almost all properties of  "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse" as below

[image]

But while executing below cosmos document db sdk code against **partitioned collection** most of properties of  "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse" returns default values as below

[image]

Any reason for these 2 different behaviors of FeedResponse against partitioned & non-partitioned collection? please clarify

Code Used:

```
                var docClient = await _documentClient;
                var docDb = await _documentDatabase;
                var docCollection = await _documentCollection;

                var queryFeed = new FeedOptions()
                {
                    MaxItemCount = -1,
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                };

                var documentCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(docDb.Id, docCollection.Id);

                IDocumentQuery<T> query = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri, queryFeed).AsDocumentQuery();

                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(); //interested in feedResponse.ContentLocation property specifically
                    result.AddRange(page);
                }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the same access permissions on both databases?

Comment: How/where to verify access permissions on both databases? but they are under same cosmodb account

Comment: It doesn't seems like permissions related issue, whenever I create new container WITHOUT partition key via sdk & query it, I can be able to get most of "FeedResponse" properties but once I have created new container WITH partition key & query it, most of "FeedResponse" properties are returned with default values. Introducing partition key in collection makes the difference in FeedResponse property values, any suggestion (or) work around to get "FeedResponse" properties with their respective values but not default values while querying against partitioned collections.

Comment: Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the CosmosDB Engineering team. For getting quota/usage statistics for partitioned collections, the user needs to explicitly specify the RequestOptions.PopulateQuotaInfo option to true. CosmosDB does not provide quota/usage statistics for partitioned collections by default since it involves a fanout read to all the partitions of the collection.

Comment: As mentioned in the above code, for fanout read queries I'm using 'CreateDocumentQuery' to read all partition & it is NOT taking  'RequestOptions' as parameter. So how to include 'RequestOptions' in fan out read queries WITHOUT impacting response time.

Comment: Is there any other way to fan out read query without using 'CreateDocumentQuery' in efficient manner? Any sample with fan out read queries by including 'RequestOptions' would be appreciated as it is not possible to include 'RequestOptions' in 'CreateDocumentQuery'.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were observing the difference on a ReadDocumentCollectionAsync call. Any particular reason why you need ResourceQuotaUsage on the response headers in your query? Can you just ignore the difference? This probably requires a follow up on our end to stop emitting the quota information in the response.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in feedResponse.ContentLocation(parent content location) property from the below code snippet . IDocumentQuery<T> query = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri, queryFeed).AsDocumentQuery();while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {                    var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>() ;result.AddRange(feedResponse );
                }. Also suggest me if there is any other way to get parent content location? If not possible using feed response against partitioned collections.

Comment: It appears that the content location is the same as the DocumentCollection's SelfLink property. This is a property of the DocumentCollection and has nothing to do with the query itself, and does not change depending on the collection's partitioning scheme. You can issue a ReadDocumentCollectionAsync and look at the SelfLink property.

Comment: Any other solution please. Me too thought the same & already verified the assumption against non partitioned collection, content location is NOT the same as the DocumentCollection's SelfLink property.  For example:- docCollection.SelfLink = "dbs/qcNKAA==/colls/qcNKANhuRwE=/"; where as feedResponse .ContentLocation = "dbs/devdb/colls/billingmodel"

Comment: docCollection.SelfLink = "dbs/qcNKAA==/colls/qcNKANhuRwE=/"; where as feedResponse .ContentLocation = "dbs/devdb/colls/billingmodel", May be SelfLink is  encryption of ContentLocation. Not sure.